# Adding a public method to a polymer element (like the go function in core-ajax)

Tags: javascript, polymer

I want to add a public function to a polymer element, just like the go() method in core-ajax. This is what I am doing right now -

```
Polymer('data-pane',{
    ready: function (){
        this.data = [];
    },
    shoveData: function (){
        console.log("what what what what");
    }
});
```

But I am getting error when I try to call shoveData() on the element (in index.html, where I am actually using it) that the function is undefined.

here's the calling snippet:

```
window.addEventListener("polymer-ready", function(){
    window.addEventListener("facebook-signin-success", function(){
        console.log("You are logged in");
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log(response);

            var pane = document.querySelector("data-pane");
            pane.data = response;
            pane.shoveData();
        });
     });
});
```

and the error message is -

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (on chrome)
TypeError: pane.shoveData is not a function (on FF)
```

How to sort this out ?

Comment: could you post your calling code example

Comment: There are some syntax errors in your definition. `polymer` needs to be `Polymer`, and `data: []` is not a correct function body (I think you mean `this.data = [];`).

Comment: You may have to wait for `polymer-ready` in your main script. I'm just guessing because you haven't shown the calling code (as Ajay mentioned). `addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() { dataPane.shoveData(); });`.

Comment: @AjayBeniwal: edited to include the calling portion.

Comment: @ScottMiles: yes, I have it surrounded in an eventListener for polymer-ready event, inside which I am using another another event that is fired by a polymer element. 
The thing is that the console is not throwing any error on the pane variable itself being undefined, `if(typeof(pane) != undefined)` passes, and no error either on assigning response to pane.data

Comment: The likely cause is that `data-pane` is not being upgraded (iow, the element registration is not happening). There are many things that could cause this, from syntax errors, to simply failing to import the element code. The basic code is fine: http://jsbin.com/samog/1/edit

Comment: @ScottMiles: I am an idiot. Thanks for pointing out the first place where I should have looked.